# Authenticating mobile app client to AWS API Gateway (social login)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, openid-connect, aws-api-gateway

I have an AWS Lambda exposed through API Gateway. I want to consume that service from (native) mobile app and browser clients.

I'd like the user to be able to use a social login like Google or Facebook, so perhaps OpenIDConnect is part of the answer?

Any tutorials or guidance on how to do this? I feel like I reinvent the wheel every time. Must be a way to get this done quickly?

Using dynamodb for persistence if that matters. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [Amazon Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/), you can translate your users' Facebook or Google credentials to AWS credentials. You would then just need to sign your requests to API Gateway with those credentials. If you use [API Gateway's generated SDKs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk.html), this is all supported by default.

Comment: Very, very nice. Just what I was hoping to find, thanks!